# Calling /ads_post returns empty data on specific pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I am using FB Graph API with the endpoint /ads_posts to retrieve the latest comments of my pages. I am currently testing on the Graph API Explorer.

My Problem:
On specific pages (where i have the same admin rights on the page) I get an empty answer when calling: PAGEID/ads_posts
When I add `?include_inline_create=true` as parameter it returns some data, but only the postings with `"message": "{{product.brand}}"` -  which are not the correct ads posts of this page.

What is weird is, that it works for other pages where I am admin as well and I cannot tell the difference between those.
Also shouldn't PAGEID/ads_posts return organic postings as well?
PAGEID/posts returns all organic postings as expected - but its weird that they are not available via ads_posts.

Permissions:

- user_events
- email read_insights
- user_managed_groups groups_show_list
- pages_manage_cta
- pages_manage_instant_articles
- pages_show_list
- read_page_mailboxes
- ads_management
- ads_read
- business_management
- pages_messaging pages_messaging_phone_number
- pages_messaging_subscriptions
- publish_to_groups
- groups_access_member_info page_events
- pages_read_engagement
- pages_manage_metadata
- pages_read_user_content
- pages_manage_ads
- pages_manage_posts
- pages_manage_engagement
- public_profile

Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 0):

I think `"{{product.brand}}"` means dynamic ads

Comment: okay this could be. But is there a way to actually get the caption or caption variations for this dynamic ads?

Comment: dynamic ads means there is going to generate lots of posts, so the `"{{product.brand}}"` is actually a **shell post** refrencing other actual posts.

Comment: so the variants have other post IDs that are available via the graph API & the shell post is more or less not available / visible on FB?

Comment: yeah, other post ids can be retrieved from /act_xxx/adcreatives GET API, shell posts have their own post ids as well.